# I have a database in PostGIS, is possible using CartoDB? or I need another map server?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto

I have a data base in PostgreSQL/PostGIS, and I want to offer to my users a way of visualize it, Is it CartoDB the best option? It is possible? Or which is the best option around?

(Please provide links to tutorials or something similar)

Comment: You need to provide some more information or it is just like asking which car is the best... So, how many users do you have, is it just a few well-defined maps you want to create, should the users be able to create/edit them on their own, are you all within the same organization or is some of the users in the public, do you have a budget, is the data access-protected in some way etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depend on your needs and what kind of data you want to show.

You can use CartoDB **as a service** or **install it** using your own PostgreSQL/PostGIS database.

### Service

If you use CartoDB as a service you have to [create an account](https://cartodb.com/signup) on [cartodb.com](http://cartodb.com) and put there the tables with the data needed to show your map.

You have [different options depending on your needs](https://cartodb.com/pricing/).

### Install

CartoDB is open source and uses PostgreSQL/PostGIS so you can [install it on your server](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb) or get a [private instance](https://cartodb.com/pricing/#/enterprise) from cartodb and use **your own database** (as long you keep the tables CartoDB needs to work).

### Other options

- You should check also [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) that has a cool **tool** called [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) and it's also very good to do nice maps.
- You also can do something with [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) and [LeafletJS](http://leafletjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If your users are desktop / on your LAN, then QGIS is the best way to go.

If you are talking about visualizing your PostGIS data over the web, I think GeoServer or Mapnik is the way to go...